# Grok learning- "How many words"

Tags: python

I'm doing a question on grok learning, it asks for this:

> You are learning a new language, and are having a competition to see how many unique words you know in it to test your vocabulary learning.
>
> Write a program where you can enter one word at a time, and be told how many unique words you have entered. You should not count duplicates. The program should stop asking for more words when you enter a blank line.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Word: Chat 
> Word: Chien   
> Word: Chat   
> Word: Escargot
> Word: 
>
> You know 3 unique word(s)!
> ```
>
> ​and
>
> ```
> Word: Katze    
> Word: Hund   
> Word: Maus  
> Word: Papagei   
> Word: Schlange 
> Word: 
>
> You know 5 unique word(s)!
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> Word: Salam   
> Word: 
>
> You know 1 unique word(s)!
> ```

I cannot get it to work when there are multiple duplicates, here is my code:

```
word = input("Word: ")
l = []
l.append(word)
words = 1
while word != "":
    if word in l:
        word = input("Word: ")
    else:
        words = 1 + words
        word = input("Word: ")
print("You know " + str(words) , "unique word(s)!" )
```

Comment: You can use a set. It exactly designed for these things. Here is a link to the set documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: You never append anything to `l` after the first time.

Comment: If you use `words` to count the number of words you should initialize it to `0` and not to `1` (to include the case when the user doesn't know any word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a set this problem can be solved easily:

```
l = set()
while True:
    new_word = input("Word:")
    if new_word=="":
        break
    l.add(new_word)
print("You know " + str(len(l)) , "unique word(s)!" )
```

This is a good example for the power of the Python standard library. Usually if you have a problem there already is a good solution in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way where you do not necessarily have to use the `set()` function. But it is still best if you learn about the `set()` function anyway.

Here's the code that doesn't need a `set()` function, but still works fine:

```
words = []
word = input('Word: ')
while word != '':
    if word not in words:
        words.append(word)
    word = input('Word: ')
print('You know', len(words), 'unique word(s)!')
```